# Error while comparing value of $_POST with value stored in json file in PHP

Tags: php, html, json, forms, post

I am working on a project in which I have used JSON file to store data and used PHP to print it. But while comparing the value from $_POST, if it has spaces then comparison is not working otherwise there is no issue
This is what I am doing

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents("location-to-my-file-storage/".$_POST['mandi']."/".$_POST['crop'].".json");
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
foreach($json['crop'] as $data)
{
if ($data['name'] == $_POST['name'])
//This if statement is responsible for error
/* if $_POST['name'] = some value, then it's not working
   but for $_POST['name'] = someValue, it is working properly

   I have also tried    if ($data['name'] == "$_POST['name'])" 
   but this is not working also 
   */
{
 /******
   *do some printing here
   */
 }
```

You can see a demo at http://divakarparashar.hol.es/innovation/en/user/farmer/price-calc.php

Select anything from two drop down list and click on available crops, it gives list for available crop. here comes the error, for a value with spaces like the first one 'Acorn Squash' nothing is happening, but for a value that has no space in it like 'Amarnath' every thing is working properly.

The same thing happened when I go for a mandi name or crop type with spaces in it, for the statement

```
$Jsonfile = file_get_contents("location-to-my-file-storage/".$_POST['nameMandi']."/".$_POST['cropType'].".json");
```

Where I am getting wrong ..??

Comment: try error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - *"but for a value that has no space in it like 'Amarnath' every thing is working properly."* - then try `trim()`.

Comment: yes trim the post and the data and compare

Comment: What's the actual path/file name to the `Acorn Squash` json file?

Comment: @jon the path file name depends on the other two selections from the drop down list, they are stored in a variable, So actual path varies on variation of choice. I added the link to demo in case you haven't checked that.

Comment: @nassim from the if statement the data is compared from a json file, where it is stored as 
              {
  "name":"Acorn Squash",
  "variety" :"Hybrid",
  "rate":1800,
  "description":"This is description of the hybrid product"
           },
So, using trim will stop it from comparing from actual string in the json file.

Comment: @Divakar, why You are not using `id's` instead of Names inside `<select>` ? Just create json array with key=>value pair and problem will be solved.

See example:

https://jsfiddle.net/zejur/oL9smt0m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check your dropdown i.e `<option>` tags.

The `value` has cutted string in there thats why comparison is not working.

```
<select name="name" class="w3-btn w3-green w3-round w3-input">
        <option name="crop" value="Acorn" squash="">Acorn Squash</option>
        <option name="crop" value="Alfalfa" sprout="">Alfalfa Sprout</option>
        <option name="crop" value="Amaranath">Amaranath</option>
```